# Merge specific fields of array indexes with duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working with a `JSON` dataset provided via `CSV` file from my client. I have processed the `CSV` into a `JSON` format.

I have the following result (dataset reduced from 1304 to 2 for readability)

```
"1": {
    "title": "Abercarn RFC",
    "address": "High Street, Abercarn, Newport, Gwent",
    "postcode": "NP11 5GQ",
    "category": "Club",
    "website": "http://abercarn.rfc.wales",
},

"2": {
    "title": "Abercarn RFC",
    "address": "High Street, Abercarn, Newport, Gwent",
    "postcode": "NP11 5GQ",
    "category": "Seniors",
    "website": "http://abercarn.rfc.wales",
}
```

I want to be able to loop through my array (pre-`json_encode($array)`) and merge these objects but preserve **both** the `category` values into a CSV list, so the ideal output in this case will be

```
"category": "Club, Seniors"
```

I am happy to simply merge all the other fields as they are consistently the same across the data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with simple loop (I used the `title` to define similarity between element but you can change that):

```
$arr = array(["title" => "Abercarn RFC", "category"=> "Club"], ["title" => "other title", "category"=> "BlaBla"], ["title" => "Abercarn RFC", "category"=> "Seniors"]);

$res = array();
foreach($arr as $e) {
    if (isset($res[$e["title"]]))
        $res[$e["title"]]["category"] .=   ", " . $e["category"];
    else $res[$e["title"]] = $e;
}
```

If you want to remove the array key you can use `array_values`.

`$res` will be your desire output.